# How to draw an arrow next to the rectangle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw arrows horizontally or vertically beside to rectangle. 
How may I code for it in overleaf code? with tikz package or else

```
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[black, thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,2) node[pos=.5] {text};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\node[minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick](n) {text};
\draw[-latex,thick] (n.east) -- ++ (2,0);
\draw[-latex,thick] (n.north) -- ++ (0,2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`

Comment: In that code how to define position of node?

Comment: As long as you only have one node, the position is meaningless (unless you are doing an `overlay` picture). If you have more stuff in the `tikzpicture`, you can say `\node[minimum width=3cm,minimum height=2cm,draw,thick](n) at (1.5,1) {text};`. However a great feature of tikz is relative positioning, so in many situations you do not need to use explicit coordinates but rather load the `positioning` library and put the nodes relative to each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@marmot has proposed a nice approach in the comment. Here I use another way, which is based on coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw[black, thick] (0,0) rectangle (3,2) node[pos=.5] {text};
\draw[stealth-stealth] (-.2,0) -- (-.2,2) node[midway,above,sloped] {\SI{2}{cm}};
\draw[stealth-stealth] (0,2.2) -- (3,2.2) node[midway,above] {\SI{3}{cm}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]